# Changing objective and condition, are there any relations?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Are there any results discussing about the relations between the two following optimization problems?

\begin{align}
 \text{ (P1) } \hspace{0.5cm} \min \hspace{0.5cm} & \langle a, x  \rangle\\
  \text{ s.t. } \hspace{0.5cm} & ||x||_1=b\\
  & x\geq 0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
 \text{ (P2) } \hspace{0.5cm} \min \hspace{0.5cm} & ||x||_1 \\
  \text{ s.t. } \hspace{0.5cm} & \langle c, x  \rangle =d\\
  & x\geq 0
\end{align}
where $a,c,x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $b,d\in \mathbb R$.

*Ps. Any related information is also appreciated!*

Comment: Is there a reason that you expect some relationship?

Comment: I am trying to solve a variant version of (P2) in a functional space instead of $\mathbb R^n$. What i know now is that (P1) in a functional space is solvable. So  I assume that there is some relation between them.

Comment: Note that $\|x\|_1 = e^T x$ above since $x \ge 0$. $e$ is the vector of ones.

Comment: there is no obvious relationship unless $a=c$

Comment: Well, that is true, but structurally they are essentially the same problem.